# Is there a do-not-retry flag for angular ajax requests?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, google-chrome, timeout

I noticed that an ajax request was taking too long, and apparently, after a while Chrome decided to execute the request again. So I ended with two duplicated ajax requests (and thus two database entries).

I googled about this Chrome behaviour and someone said that it was possible to tell Chrome not to retry ajax requests after timeout with a *"do not retry"* flag.

Questions:

- Is it possible in `angular` to setup the `$http` with this flag?
- Any other solution? The first time I had this problem I thought it was a "double click" problem, but now I'm pretty sure it is not. (In fact I always disable buttons while the request is working)

Answer (score 1):

I feel like I don't have enough information, so don't downvote me if this is wrong. But when you say, a "do not retry" flag, do you mean a custom header? If so, you can attach custom headers in your config like this, which will attach the header to any and all http requests throughout your application (I personally have used this for including the `X-Requested-With` header:

```
.config(["$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['do-not-retry'] = 'true';
}])
```